# Confusion regarding nchar in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sqldatatypes

I have trouble understanding below excerpt from [`nchar` and `nvarchar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/ms186939.aspx)

It says:

> nchar [ ( n ) ]
>
> Fixed-length Unicode string data. n defines the string length and must be a value from 1 through 4,000. The storage size is two times n bytes. When the collation code page uses double-byte characters, the storage size is still n bytes. Depending on the string, the storage size of n bytes can be less than the value specified for n. The ISO synonyms for nchar are national char and national character..

I find some contradictions in the above statements like:

See the 2nd sentence where it says **storage size is two times n bytes** and in the next sentence it says **the storage size is still n bytes**. In the first sentence it says that it has fixed-length and in 4th sentence it says the storage size of n bytes can be less than the value specified for n.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The last one isn't a contradiction.  You can assign fewer than 'n' characters to an nchar(n) column.  The column still takes up 2*n bytes, and the value is actually padded out to n characters.

Comment: I suspect the documentation is erroneous.  I think they meant "the storage size is still two times n bytes", because nchar is fixed length.

Comment: @pmbAustin: I understand what you want to say, in fact I share the same opinion but the documentation says that ->>> the storage size of n bytes can be less than the value specified for n. I think storage size should be fixed and in fact that's why padding is done. Isn't it?

Comment: `NCHAR` is a **fixed length** type - it will **always** use as many characters as defined; and `NCHAR` is an Unicode type, which means **2 bytes per character**. So `NCHAR(20)` is ***always*** going to take **40 bytes**.

Comment: @marc_s : So the sql server document needs to be corrected :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, nchar and nvarchar stores unicode strings. 
The n you see is the number of characters that will be stored in the nchar column, or the maximum number of characters that will be stored in the nvarchar column.
Depending on the string, the storage size of the nchar may be smaller then n. since nchar is fixed lenght, it means that it will add white spaces to strings that are shorter then n. this means that if you store the string 'h' in an nchar(6) column, it will be regarded as 'h' with 5 trailing spaces. I'm guessing that the trailing spaces are not actually stored in the database, therefor the storage size can be less than n.

In nvarchar, however, this is not the case. nvarchar will always have the storage size of (n*2) + 2 bytes.

Comment: The thing you are guessing about the storage is my actual confusion :)